# Open and read mtz file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file

I am currently working on a HTML/Javascript project that takes an mtz file and presents the information on it in a more visually accessible platform but am not reallly sure how:

1. I open an mtz file in javascript
2. Read the file character by character OR line by line to take this info and put it into a dynamic table

Extra info on MTZ files:

> MTZ file format contains reflection data. It uses fixed length logical
>   'records' written in a byte stream with, in general, four bytes for
>   each data item, with a minimum of 3 columns and currently a maximum of
>   200 columns of data per record. Additional information (title, cell
>   dimensions, column labels, symmetry information, resolution range,
>   history information and, if necessary, batch titles and orientation
>   data) is found in labelled header records. The columns of the
>   reflection data records are identified by alphanumeric labels held as
>   part of the file header information.

Is there anyone who has previous experience with mtz files and could help me a little?

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide more information on `mtz` files? Maybe the closely resemble some file format that plenty of tooling exists for.

Comment: Hi, I've edited the question to contain info about MTZ files

Comment: Try to parse the header information first, verify your results (for example check if the number of records or length of data is correct). Create a JavaScript object to hold the various sections (identified in the header) and attach the sections as objects to it. Your description of the file format is too vague to give more specific directions.